# LINQ query JOIN two tables for Web API controller method

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am really poor at LINQ and can't figure out a simple problem. I have a MVC Web API that has a controller. I have a method inside the controller to return back data for comments entered by user for an item.

The data structure is simple - Comments and User tables with UserID column acting as the foreign key

To solve the problem, I have the following method, which has a LINQ query to do a join between Comments and User tables and return back an object in a new extended object that combines the Comments and User details. I cant seem to grab data from the User table. Can someone please help?

```
public IQueryable<CommentsWithUserDetails> GetReviewsWithUserByItem(int ID)
    {
        var query = from x in db.Comments
                    join y in db.Users on x.CommentsUserID equals y.UserID into z
                    where x.CommentsItemID.Equals(ID)
                    select new CommentsWithUserDetails
                    {
                        CommentsUserID = x.CommentsUserID,
                        CommentsText = x.CommentsText,
                        CommentsRating = x.CommentsRating,
                        CommentsDate = x.CommentsDate,
                        UserFirstName = y.FirstName,
                        UserLastName = y.LastName,
                        UserPictureURL = y.PictureURL
                    };

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: You joined everything into z, so use z instead of x!

Comment: you can also remove `into z`

Comment: actually...why do you even have the where clause. Web API allows you to use OData query strings to apply a where "filter".

Comment: Just remove the `into z`, unless you want an outer join.

Comment: thanks guys, it is as simple as removing the into z from the query!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is just to remove the 'into z' part from the query, yes as simple as that!

As pointed by @Nilesh and @Gert Arnold